# How to read the tree structure from file using Java

Tags: java, file, readfile

I'm trying to read from a .txt file a tree structure like that:

```
parent                   Type     short description1
   .firstChild           Type     short description2
       .firstNephew      Type     short description3
   .secondChild          Type     short description4
       .firstNephew      Type     short description5
       .secondNephew     Type     short description6

parent.firstChild = value1
parent.firstChild.firstNephew = value2
parent.secondChild = value3
parent.secondChild.firstNephew = value4
parent.secondChild.secondNephew = value5
```

And I want the output to be a list with Test objects like that (the expected output):

[parent, type, value1, short description1,
firstChild, type, value2, short description2,
firstNephew, type, value3, short description3,
secondChild, type, value4, short description4,
firstNephew, type, value5, short description5,
secondNephew, type, value6, short description6]

So far I have:

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private String description;
    public Test(String name, String type, String value, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", type: " + type + ", value: " + value + ", description: " + description;
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("files/file.txt")).filter(line -> !line.isEmpty())) {
            List<Test> myObjectsList = lines.map(line -> {
                String[] arr = line.trim().split(" +", 3);
                return new Test(arr[0], arr[1], null, arr[2]);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            myObjectsList.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: You can actually check number of spaces before each line, 3 <=> child, 6 <=> nephew

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that you want to check generation of child. What you actually want to do, cuz U didn't write this. Remove dots from begining?

Comment: If you are trying to load tree structure you should build a graph insteed of loading this into one list

Comment: @Oskar, I want to have this output: [parent, type, value1, short description1,
firstChild, type, value2, short description2,
firstNephew, type, value3, short description3,
secondChild, type, value4, short description4,
firstNephew, type, value5, short description5,
secondNephew, type, value6, short description6], but I don't know how to read the value for each tree node